# Keras tuner - distributed hyperparameter tuning

Tags: python, kubernetes, keras, neural-network, hyperparameters

Due to very small amount of documentation I would like to ask if anyone has some experience with [distributed hyperparameter tuning via Keras tuner](https://keras.io/guides/keras_tuner/distributed_tuning/#example-code) and could provide an example.

What I've done so far:

- Keras Bayesian optimization runs successfully on my HyperModel without distributed computation
- Keras Random search optimization runs successfully on my HyperModel without distributed computation
- I've tried to run "chief script" on BinderHub instance A and "worker script" on BinderHub instance B. Both seems to be idle and stuck. I deduce it from the fact that no output is produced after some logging from GPU and after keyboard interrupt I can see that the chief is sleeping:

```
userXXX@machineYYY:~$ ./tune.sh 
2022-10-05 14:33:42.266134: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 36507 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA A40, pci bus id: 0000:27:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
WARNING:tensorflow:From tuning.py:53: The name tf.keras.backend.set_session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session instead.

From tuning.py:53: The name tf.keras.backend.set_session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session instead.

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "tuning.py", line 443, in <module>
    tuner = keras_tuner.BayesianOptimization(
  File "/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_tuner/tuners/bayesian.py", line 460, in __init__
    super(
  File "/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_tuner/engine/tuner.py", line 110, in __init__
    super(Tuner, self).__init__(
  File "/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_tuner/engine/base_tuner.py", line 89, in __init__
    oracle_chief.start_server(self.oracle)
  File "/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_tuner/distribute/oracle_chief.py", line 81, in start_server
    time.sleep(30)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Script *tune.sh* on BinderHub instance A:

```
export KERASTUNER_TUNER_ID="chief"
export KERASTUNER_ORACLE_IP="10.42.209.12" #ip of current host
export KERASTUNER_ORACLE_PORT="8000"

python tuning.py
```

Script *tune.sh* on BinderHub instance B:

```
export KERASTUNER_TUNER_ID="tuner0"
export KERASTUNER_ORACLE_IP="10.42.209.12" #ip of chief host
export KERASTUNER_ORACLE_PORT="8000"

python tuning.py
```

Couldn't this distributed hyperparameter tuning be run in Kubernetes? It seems to me like an ideal tool but I can't find any documentation on connecting Kubernetes and Keras tuner.